# What's the equation for a fitted smoothing spline?

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I have set of data in .csv (Data file is attached) file and I want to find the best fit line for that data. I was not able to get good fitting using nonlinear fittings (May be I am poor in using nonlinear fitting in R).
But I was able to use *smooth.spline* function and fit the data properly as shown in the attached image. My requirement is:
1. get the equation of fitted spline function or
2. use nonlinear fitting model to get the best fit equation
This is the command I used to do the smooth.spline fitting

```
filePath = "E:/1_Modulated_function_pmf/R_Fitting/"
readData = read.csv(paste0(filePath, "data.csv"))
x_data<-readData$X_data
y_data<-readData$Y_data
plot(x_data,y_data)
spline <- smooth.spline(x_data,y_data,df=20)
lines(spline, col="red")
```

I want to get the equation of fitted spline function. What is the syntax to get the equation of spline function? or use best nonlinear fitting model to fit the data. The X and Y data are given below:

```
X_data(2.96E-01,2.98E-01,3.00E-01,3.02E-01,3.04E-01,3.06E-01,3.08E-01,3.10E-01,3.12E-01,3.14E-01,3.16E-01,3.18E-01,3.20E-01,3.22E-01,3.24E-01,3.26E-01,3.28E-01,3.30E-01,3.32E-01,3.34E-01,3.36E-01,3.38E-01,3.40E-01,3.42E-01,3.44E-01,3.46E-01,3.48E-01,3.50E-01,3.52E-01,3.54E-01,3.56E-01,3.58E-01,3.60E-01,3.62E-01,3.64E-01,3.66E-01,3.68E-01,3.70E-01,3.72E-01,3.74E-01,3.76E-01,3.78E-01,3.80E-01,3.82E-01,3.84E-01,3.86E-01,3.88E-01,3.90E-01,3.92E-01,3.94E-01,3.96E-01,3.98E-01,4.00E-01,4.02E-01,4.04E-01,4.06E-01,4.08E-01,4.10E-01,4.12E-01,4.14E-01,4.16E-01,4.18E-01,4.20E-01,4.22E-01,4.24E-01,4.26E-01,4.28E-01,4.30E-01,4.32E-01,4.34E-01,4.36E-01,4.38E-01,4.40E-01,4.42E-01,4.44E-01,4.46E-01,4.48E-01,4.50E-01,4.52E-01,4.54E-01,4.56E-01,4.58E-01,4.60E-01,4.62E-01,4.64E-01,4.66E-01,4.68E-01,4.70E-01,4.72E-01,4.74E-01,4.76E-01,4.78E-01,4.80E-01,4.82E-01,4.84E-01,4.86E-01,4.88E-01,4.90E-01,4.92E-01,4.94E-01,4.96E-01,4.98E-01,5.00E-01,5.02E-01,5.04E-01,5.06E-01,5.08E-01,5.10E-01,5.12E-01,5.14E-01,5.16E-01,5.18E-01,5.20E-01,5.22E-01,5.24E-01,5.26E-01,5.28E-01,5.30E-01,5.32E-01,5.34E-01,5.36E-01,5.38E-01,5.40E-01,5.42E-01,5.44E-01,5.46E-01,5.48E-01,5.50E-01,5.52E-01,5.54E-01,5.56E-01,5.58E-01,5.60E-01,5.62E-01,5.64E-01,5.66E-01,5.68E-01,5.70E-01,5.72E-01,5.74E-01,5.76E-01,5.78E-01,5.80E-01,5.82E-01,5.84E-01,5.86E-01,5.88E-01,5.90E-01,5.92E-01,5.94E-01,5.96E-01,5.98E-01,6.00E-01,6.02E-01,6.04E-01,6.06E-01,6.08E-01,6.10E-01,6.12E-01,6.14E-01,6.16E-01,6.18E-01,6.20E-01,6.22E-01,6.24E-01,6.26E-01,6.28E-01,6.30E-01,6.32E-01,6.34E-01,6.36E-01,6.38E-01,6.40E-01,6.42E-01,6.44E-01,6.46E-01,6.48E-01,6.50E-01,6.52E-01,6.54E-01,6.56E-01,6.58E-01,6.60E-01,6.62E-01,6.64E-01,6.66E-01,6.68E-01,6.70E-01,6.72E-01,6.74E-01,6.76E-01,6.78E-01,6.80E-01,6.82E-01,6.84E-01,6.86E-01,6.88E-01,6.90E-01,6.92E-01,6.94E-01,6.96E-01,6.98E-01,7.00E-01,7.02E-01,7.04E-01,7.06E-01,7.08E-01,7.10E-01,7.12E-01,7.14E-01,7.16E-01,7.18E-01,7.20E-01,7.22E-01,7.24E-01,7.26E-01,7.28E-01,7.30E-01,7.32E-01,7.34E-01,7.36E-01,7.38E-01,7.40E-01,7.42E-01,7.44E-01,7.46E-01,7.48E-01,7.50E-01,7.52E-01,7.54E-01,7.56E-01,7.58E-01,7.60E-01,7.62E-01,7.64E-01,7.66E-01,7.68E-01,7.70E-01,7.72E-01,7.74E-01,7.76E-01,7.78E-01,7.80E-01,7.82E-01,7.84E-01,7.86E-01,7.88E-01,7.90E-01,7.92E-01,7.94E-01,7.96E-01,7.98E-01,8.00E-01,8.02E-01,8.04E-01,8.06E-01,8.08E-01,8.10E-01,8.12E-01,8.14E-01,8.16E-01,8.18E-01,8.20E-01,8.22E-01,8.24E-01,8.26E-01,8.28E-01,8.30E-01,8.32E-01,8.34E-01,8.36E-01,8.38E-01,8.40E-01,8.42E-01,8.44E-01,8.46E-01,8.48E-01,8.50E-01,8.52E-01,8.54E-01,8.56E-01,8.58E-01,8.60E-01,8.62E-01,8.64E-01,8.66E-01,8.68E-01,8.70E-01,8.72E-01,8.74E-01,8.76E-01,8.78E-01,8.80E-01,8.82E-01,8.84E-01,8.86E-01,8.88E-01,8.90E-01,8.92E-01,8.94E-01,8.96E-01,8.98E-01,9.00E-01,9.02E-01,9.04E-01,9.06E-01,9.08E-01,9.10E-01,9.12E-01,9.14E-01,9.16E-01,9.18E-01,9.20E-01,9.22E-01,9.24E-01,9.26E-01,9.28E-01,9.30E-01,9.32E-01,9.34E-01,9.36E-01,9.38E-01,9.40E-01,9.42E-01,9.44E-01,9.46E-01,9.48E-01,9.50E-01,9.52E-01,9.54E-01,9.56E-01,9.58E-01,9.60E-01,9.62E-01,9.64E-01,9.66E-01,9.68E-01,9.70E-01,9.72E-01,9.74E-01,9.76E-01,9.78E-01,9.80E-01,9.82E-01,9.84E-01,9.86E-01,9.88E-01,9.90E-01,9.92E-01,9.94E-01,9.96E-01,9.98E-01,1.00E+00,1.00E+00,1.00E+00,1.01E+00,1.01E+00,1.01E+00,1.01E+00,1.01E+00,1.02E+00,1.02E+00,1.02E+00,1.02E+00,1.02E+00,1.03E+00,1.03E+00,1.03E+00,1.03E+00,1.03E+00,1.04E+00,1.04E+00,1.04E+00,1.04E+00,1.04E+00,1.05E+00,1.05E+00,1.05E+00,1.05E+00,1.05E+00,1.06E+00,1.06E+00,1.06E+00,1.06E+00,1.06E+00,1.07E+00,1.07E+00,1.07E+00,1.07E+00,1.07E+00,1.08E+00,1.08E+00,1.08E+00,1.08E+00,1.08E+00,1.09E+00,1.09E+00,1.09E+00,1.09E+00,1.09E+00,1.10E+00,1.10E+00,1.10E+00,1.10E+00,1.10E+00,1.11E+00,1.11E+00,1.11E+00,1.11E+00,1.11E+00,1.12E+00,1.12E+00,1.12E+00,1.12E+00,1.12E+00,1.13E+00,1.13E+00,1.13E+00,1.13E+00,1.13E+00,1.14E+00,1.14E+00,1.14E+00,1.14E+00,1.14E+00,1.15E+00,1.15E+00,1.15E+00,1.15E+00,1.15E+00,1.16E+00,1.16E+00,1.16E+00,1.16E+00,1.16E+00,1.17E+00,1.17E+00,1.17E+00,1.17E+00,1.17E+00,1.18E+00,1.18E+00,1.18E+00,1.18E+00,1.18E+00,1.19E+00,1.19E+00,1.19E+00,1.19E+00,1.19E+00,1.20E+00)
Y_data(8.10E+00,6.34E+00,5.29E+00,4.69E+00,4.34E+00,4.11E+00,3.93E+00,3.77E+00,3.62E+00,3.48E+00,3.33E+00,3.19E+00,3.05E+00,2.92E+00,2.79E+00,2.66E+00,2.53E+00,2.41E+00,2.29E+00,2.16E+00,2.04E+00,1.91E+00,1.79E+00,1.67E+00,1.55E+00,1.44E+00,1.32E+00,1.21E+00,1.11E+00,1.01E+00,9.06E-01,8.10E-01,7.17E-01,6.28E-01,5.44E-01,4.65E-01,3.90E-01,3.22E-01,2.59E-01,2.02E-01,1.51E-01,1.06E-01,6.79E-02,3.64E-02,1.17E-02,-5.97E-03,-1.68E-02,-2.10E-02,-1.86E-02,-1.01E-02,4.13E-03,2.38E-02,4.83E-02,7.71E-02,1.10E-01,1.45E-01,1.83E-01,2.23E-01,2.63E-01,3.04E-01,3.45E-01,3.85E-01,4.25E-01,4.64E-01,5.01E-01,5.38E-01,5.73E-01,6.08E-01,6.41E-01,6.74E-01,7.06E-01,7.39E-01,7.71E-01,8.03E-01,8.34E-01,8.66E-01,8.97E-01,9.28E-01,9.58E-01,9.87E-01,1.02E+00,1.04E+00,1.07E+00,1.10E+00,1.12E+00,1.14E+00,1.16E+00,1.18E+00,1.20E+00,1.21E+00,1.23E+00,1.24E+00,1.25E+00,1.25E+00,1.26E+00,1.26E+00,1.26E+00,1.26E+00,1.26E+00,1.25E+00,1.25E+00,1.24E+00,1.23E+00,1.22E+00,1.21E+00,1.19E+00,1.18E+00,1.16E+00,1.15E+00,1.13E+00,1.11E+00,1.09E+00,1.07E+00,1.05E+00,1.03E+00,1.01E+00,9.85E-01,9.64E-01,9.44E-01,9.23E-01,9.03E-01,8.83E-01,8.64E-01,8.45E-01,8.27E-01,8.09E-01,7.92E-01,7.75E-01,7.59E-01,7.43E-01,7.28E-01,7.13E-01,6.99E-01,6.85E-01,6.71E-01,6.58E-01,6.45E-01,6.32E-01,6.21E-01,6.10E-01,6.00E-01,5.90E-01,5.81E-01,5.72E-01,5.64E-01,5.57E-01,5.49E-01,5.42E-01,5.35E-01,5.29E-01,5.23E-01,5.17E-01,5.12E-01,5.07E-01,5.03E-01,4.99E-01,4.96E-01,4.94E-01,4.91E-01,4.89E-01,4.87E-01,4.85E-01,4.83E-01,4.82E-01,4.81E-01,4.81E-01,4.81E-01,4.82E-01,4.83E-01,4.84E-01,4.86E-01,4.88E-01,4.90E-01,4.93E-01,4.96E-01,4.99E-01,5.03E-01,5.07E-01,5.11E-01,5.15E-01,5.20E-01,5.25E-01,5.31E-01,5.36E-01,5.42E-01,5.48E-01,5.54E-01,5.59E-01,5.65E-01,5.71E-01,5.77E-01,5.83E-01,5.89E-01,5.94E-01,6.00E-01,6.05E-01,6.10E-01,6.15E-01,6.20E-01,6.25E-01,6.29E-01,6.33E-01,6.36E-01,6.40E-01,6.43E-01,6.46E-01,6.49E-01,6.51E-01,6.54E-01,6.56E-01,6.57E-01,6.58E-01,6.59E-01,6.60E-01,6.60E-01,6.60E-01,6.59E-01,6.59E-01,6.58E-01,6.57E-01,6.56E-01,6.55E-01,6.53E-01,6.52E-01,6.50E-01,6.49E-01,6.47E-01,6.45E-01,6.43E-01,6.41E-01,6.40E-01,6.38E-01,6.35E-01,6.33E-01,6.31E-01,6.29E-01,6.26E-01,6.24E-01,6.22E-01,6.20E-01,6.18E-01,6.17E-01,6.15E-01,6.13E-01,6.11E-01,6.09E-01,6.07E-01,6.06E-01,6.04E-01,6.03E-01,6.02E-01,6.01E-01,6.00E-01,5.99E-01,5.98E-01,5.97E-01,5.96E-01,5.95E-01,5.95E-01,5.94E-01,5.94E-01,5.93E-01,5.93E-01,5.92E-01,5.91E-01,5.91E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.91E-01,5.91E-01,5.91E-01,5.91E-01,5.92E-01,5.92E-01,5.92E-01,5.93E-01,5.93E-01,5.93E-01,5.93E-01,5.94E-01,5.94E-01,5.94E-01,5.94E-01,5.95E-01,5.95E-01,5.96E-01,5.96E-01,5.97E-01,5.97E-01,5.97E-01,5.98E-01,5.98E-01,5.99E-01,5.99E-01,5.99E-01,6.00E-01,6.00E-01,6.01E-01,6.01E-01,6.02E-01,6.02E-01,6.03E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.05E-01,6.06E-01,6.06E-01,6.07E-01,6.07E-01,6.07E-01,6.07E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.09E-01,6.09E-01,6.10E-01,6.10E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.12E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.12E-01,6.12E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.11E-01,6.10E-01,6.10E-01,6.10E-01,6.10E-01,6.09E-01,6.09E-01,6.09E-01,6.09E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.08E-01,6.07E-01,6.07E-01,6.06E-01,6.06E-01,6.05E-01,6.05E-01,6.05E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.04E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.03E-01,6.02E-01,6.02E-01,6.02E-01,6.01E-01,6.01E-01,6.01E-01,6.00E-01,6.00E-01,5.99E-01,5.99E-01,5.98E-01,5.98E-01,5.97E-01,5.97E-01,5.96E-01,5.96E-01,5.95E-01,5.94E-01,5.94E-01,5.93E-01,5.92E-01,5.91E-01,5.90E-01,5.90E-01,5.89E-01,5.88E-01,5.87E-01,5.86E-01,5.85E-01,5.84E-01,5.83E-01,5.82E-01,5.81E-01,5.80E-01,5.80E-01,5.79E-01,5.78E-01,5.77E-01,5.76E-01,5.75E-01,5.74E-01,5.73E-01,5.72E-01,5.71E-01,5.70E-01,5.69E-01,5.68E-01,5.67E-01,5.66E-01)
```

[image]

Comment: There is no equation for the line with these methods. They are functions of the observed data that don't exist independently from them. If you want to generalize a pattern or interpret coefficients, you probably should be doing some statistical modeling rather than smoothing. Seems like your question is really more about understanding statistical methods which would be a better fit for [stats.se]. This doesn't seem like a programming question that's right for Stack Overflow.